# Excluding indexes from a HashMap

Tags: java, android, algorithm

I am trying to implement an algorithm that does the following:

If the number stored in the variable `compHand` exists, its index will be stored in `indexArray` and that index will be added to the `banIndex()` method so that, that index will never be considered again for further operation.

**OR**

if the summation of any two numbers in the list equal to `compHand`, the indexes of these number will be stored in `indexArray` and will be added to the `banIndex()` so that, they will never be considered for any further operation.

Actually, the algorithm works fine, but always if the last `value` of the hashMap is 10, then, `10` will be displayed twice? it should be displayed only once.why?
e.g: the result from this algorithm according to the `populateHash()` will be: 5,6,7,7
and it should be: 5,6,7

Any idea why that is happening?

***Code***

```
public class Test {

static HashMap<Integer, Integer> h1 = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int compHand = 10;
    populateHash(Test.h1);

    int iter = -1;
    int [] indexArray = new int[(Test.h1.size())];
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> bannedIndexHash = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();


    for (int i=1; i<=Test.h1.size(); i++) {
        if (! isBannedIndex(bannedIndexHash, i)) {
            if (i == Test.h1.size()) {
                if (compHand == Test.h1.get(i)) {
                    indexArray[++iter] = i;
                    banIndex(bannedIndexHash, i);
                }// end if
            }else {
                if (compHand == Test.h1.get(i)) {
                    indexArray[++iter] = i;
                    banIndex(bannedIndexHash, i);
                }//end if
                else {
                    for (int j=i+1; j<=Test.h1.size(); j++) {
                        if ( (! isBannedIndex(bannedIndexHash, i)) &&
                             (! isBannedIndex(bannedIndexHash, j)) ) {
                            if ( (compHand == (Test.h1.get(i)+Test.h1.get(j))) || (compHand == Test.h1.get(j)) ) {
                                if (compHand == (Test.h1.get(i)+Test.h1.get(j))) {
                                    indexArray[++iter] = i;
                                    indexArray[++iter] = j;
                                    banIndex(bannedIndexHash, i);
                                    banIndex(bannedIndexHash, j);
                                    break;
                                }//end if
                                else {
                                    if (compHand == Test.h1.get(j)) {
                                        indexArray[++iter] = j;
                                        banIndex(bannedIndexHash, j);
                                    }// end if
                                }// end else
                            }// end if-condition ||
                        }// end if-condition &&
                    }// end for (j)
                }// end else
            }//end else
        }// end ! isBannedIndex(bannedIndexHash, i)
    }// end for(i)


    if (iter > -1) {
        System.out.println("iter > -1");
        for (int i=0; i<indexArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(indexArray[i]);
        }
    }
}

private static boolean isBannedIndex(HashMap<Integer, Integer> _bannedIndexHash, int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Log.i(TAG, "@isBannedIndex(): ");

    if (!_bannedIndexHash.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i=1; i<_bannedIndexHash.size(); i++)
            if (index == _bannedIndexHash.get(i))
                return true;
        return false;
    }else
        return false;
}

private static void banIndex(HashMap<Integer, Integer> _bannedIndexHash, int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Log.i(TAG, "@banIndex(): ");

    if (_bannedIndexHash != null)
        _bannedIndexHash.put(_bannedIndexHash.size()+1, index);
}
private static void populateHash(HashMap<Integer, Integer> hash) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    hash.put(1, 1);
    hash.put(2, 3);
    hash.put(3, 1);
    hash.put(4, 1);
    hash.put(5, 10);
    hash.put(6, 10);
    hash.put(7, 10);
    /*hash.put(8, 7);
    hash.put(9, 1);
    hash.put(10, 10);
    hash.put(11, 5);
    hash.put(12, 8);
    hash.put(13, 1);
    hash.put(14, 1);
    hash.put(15, 6);
    hash.put(16, 1);
    hash.put(17, 1);
    hash.put(18, 2);*/  
}
}
```

Comment: That code is not fun to read through... maybe separate the code into more methods (which can also make debugging easier for you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reworked your code and dropped redundant if-else cascades.

My solution generates the following output (0 numbers exist due to the predefined array lenght):
iter > -1
5
6
7
0
0
0
0

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> testHashes = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        int compHand = 10;
        populateHash(testHashes);

        int iter = -1;
        int[] indexArray = new int[(testHashes.size())];
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> bannedValues = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= testHashes.size(); i++) {
            if (!isBannedIndex(bannedValues, i)) {
                if (compHand == testHashes.get(i)) {
                    indexArray[++iter] = i;
                    banIndex(bannedValues, i);
                } else {
                    for (int j = i + 1; j <= testHashes.size(); j++) {
                        if (!isBannedIndex(bannedValues, j)) {
                            if(compHand == testHashes.get(i) + testHashes.get(j)) {
                                indexArray[++iter] = i;
                                indexArray[++iter] = j;
                                banIndex(bannedValues, i);
                                banIndex(bannedValues, j);
                                break;
                            } else {
                                if (compHand == testHashes.get(j)) {
                                    indexArray[++iter] = j;
                                    banIndex(bannedValues, j);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (iter > -1) {
            System.out.println("iter > -1");
            for (int i = 0; i < indexArray.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(indexArray[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean isBannedIndex(
            final HashMap<Integer, Integer> banned, final int index) {

        return !banned.isEmpty() && banned.values().contains(index);
    }

    private static void banIndex(final HashMap<Integer, Integer> banned,
            final int index) {

        if (banned != null)
            banned.put(banned.size() + 1, index);
    }

    private static void populateHash(final HashMap<Integer, Integer> hash) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        hash.put(1, 1);
        hash.put(2, 3);
        hash.put(3, 1);
        hash.put(4, 1);
        hash.put(5, 10);
        hash.put(6, 10);
        hash.put(7, 10);
        /*
         * hash.put(8, 7); hash.put(9, 1); hash.put(10, 10); hash.put(11, 5);
         * hash.put(12, 8); hash.put(13, 1); hash.put(14, 1); hash.put(15, 6);
         * hash.put(16, 1); hash.put(17, 1); hash.put(18, 2);
         */

    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Another, tighter version could look like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    static List<Integer> resultIndexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        List<Integer> testHashes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        populateHash(testHashes);

        Integer compHand = new Integer(10);

        for(int i = 0; i < testHashes.size(); i++){
            if(isBanned(i)){
                continue;
            }
            Integer valueA = testHashes.get(i);

            if(valueA.equals(compHand)){
                resultIndexes.add(i);
            } else {
                Integer valueB = compHand - valueA;
                int index = testHashes.indexOf(valueB);

                if(!isBanned(index) && index > -1 && index != i){
                    resultIndexes.add(i);                   
                    resultIndexes.add(testHashes.indexOf(valueB));
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i : resultIndexes){
            System.out.println("Index: "+i+"; Value: "+testHashes.get(i));
        }
    }

    private static boolean isBanned(final Integer i){
        return resultIndexes.contains(i);
    }

    private static void populateHash(final List<Integer> hashes) {
        hashes.add(1);
        hashes.add(3);
        hashes.add(1);
        hashes.add(1);
        hashes.add(10);
        hashes.add(10);
        hashes.add(10);

        hashes.add(7); hashes.add(1); hashes.add(10); hashes.add(5);
        hashes.add(8); hashes.add(1); hashes.add(1); hashes.add(6);
        hashes.add(1); hashes.add(1); hashes.add(2);


    }
}
```

Console log: 
Index: 1; Value: 3
Index: 7; Value: 7
Index: 4; Value: 10
Index: 5; Value: 10
Index: 6; Value: 10
Index: 9; Value: 10
Index: 11; Value: 8
Index: 17; Value: 2

Comment: I did, but can you please mark a post as correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in `isBannedIndex` method. The right for should be `for (int i=1; i<=_bannedIndexHash.size(); i++)`
A little optimization of your code (Set instead of banned Map, and redundant check of i in second for):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {

    static HashMap<Integer, Integer> h1 = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int compHand = 10;
        populateHash(Main.h1);

        int iter = -1;
        int[] indexArray = new int[(Main.h1.size())];
        Set<Integer> bannedIndex = new HashSet<Integer>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= Main.h1.size(); i++) {
            if (!isBannedIndex(bannedIndex, i)) {
                if (i == Main.h1.size()) {
                    if (compHand == Main.h1.get(i)) {
                        indexArray[++iter] = i;
                        banIndex(bannedIndex, i);
                    }// end if
                } else {
                    if (compHand == Main.h1.get(i)) {
                        indexArray[++iter] = i;
                        banIndex(bannedIndex, i);
                    }// end if
                    else {
                        for (int j = i + 1; j <= Main.h1.size(); j++) {
                            if (!isBannedIndex(bannedIndex, j)) {
                                if ((compHand == (Main.h1.get(i) + Main.h1
                                        .get(j)))
                                        || (compHand == Main.h1.get(j))) {
                                    if (compHand == (Main.h1.get(i) + Main.h1
                                            .get(j))) {
                                        indexArray[++iter] = i;
                                        indexArray[++iter] = j;
                                        banIndex(bannedIndex, i);
                                        banIndex(bannedIndex, j);
                                        break;
                                    }// end if
                                    else {
                                        if (compHand == Main.h1.get(j)) {
                                            indexArray[++iter] = j;
                                            banIndex(bannedIndex, j);
                                        }// end if
                                    }// end else
                                }// end if-condition ||
                            }// end if-condition &&
                        }// end for (j)
                    }// end else
                }// end else
            }// end ! isBannedIndex(bannedIndexHash, i)
        }// end for(i)

        if (iter > -1) {
            System.out.println("iter > -1");
            for (int i = 0; i < indexArray.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(indexArray[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean isBannedIndex(Set<Integer> bannedIndex, int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Log.i(TAG, "@isBannedIndex(): ");

        return bannedIndex.contains(index);
    }

    private static void banIndex(Set<Integer> bannedIndex, int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Log.i(TAG, "@banIndex(): ");

        if (bannedIndex != null)
            bannedIndex.add(index);
    }

    private static void populateHash(HashMap<Integer, Integer> hash) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        hash.put(1, 1);
        hash.put(2, 3);
        hash.put(3, 1);
        hash.put(4, 1);
        hash.put(5, 10);
        hash.put(6, 10);
        hash.put(7, 10);
        /*
         * hash.put(8, 7); hash.put(9, 1); hash.put(10, 10); hash.put(11, 5);
         * hash.put(12, 8); hash.put(13, 1); hash.put(14, 1); hash.put(15, 6);
         * hash.put(16, 1); hash.put(17, 1); hash.put(18, 2);
         */

    }
}
```